# How to add multiple onClick function on a button in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a tabs.js file that needs to be connected with some data. There are 4 tabs under tabs.js and on clicking each button some data should appear. I already have some onClick functionality on the 4 tabs. I cant get hold of how can i further add another functionality to each tab so that onclick of each tab, data should appear.

Please suggest a simple solution.

Here is my piece of code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'



class Tabs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { selectedTabIndex: -1};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(index) {
        this.setState({ selectedTabIndex: index});
    }

    render() {

        const { selectedTabIndex } = this.state;
        const { tabs } = this.props;

        return (
            <ul className="tabs padding-left-large padding-top-small">
                <li className={`tab-title ${selectedTabIndex==0?'active':''}`}><button onClick={()=>{this.handleChange(0)}}>{tabs[0]}</button></li>
                <li className={`tab-title ${selectedTabIndex==1?'active':''}`}><button onClick={()=>{this.handleChange(1)}}>{tabs[1]}</button></li>
                <li className={`tab-title ${selectedTabIndex==2?'active':''}`}><button onClick={()=>{this.handleChange(2)}}>{tabs[2]}</button></li>
                <li className={`tab-title ${selectedTabIndex==3 || selectedTabIndex==-1?'active':''}`}><button onClick={()=>{this.handleChange(3)}}>{tabs[3]}</button></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }

}

export default Tabs
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to accurately help you. Are you asking how to fetch data from the selectedTabIndex? Are you asking how to call another function inside handleChange?

Comment: is data is in the same component that you want to appear?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're passing parameters to the function to me it looks like the easiest way to get each individual button to do something else would just be something like this:

```js
handleChange(index) {
    if(index === 1){
      //do something for tab 1
    }
    if(index === 2){
      //do something for tab 2
    }
    //etc.
    this.setState({ selectedTabIndex: index});
}
```